# Using a URL parameter for a results message on different page? What is a better way to accomplish this?

Tags: php, parameters, query-string, alert

I have an application where I'm using a URL parameter to trigger a results message after a certain action and a redirect. Example flow is like this:

```
1. User fills out form and clicks "Update"
2. [PHP code to update DB]
3. header('Location: [next-page.php]?message=1')
4. [PHP code on checks DB for the text of message id #1 and echo the message, (e.g. "Update successful!")]
```

This works well initially, but with a couple of problems. The URL parameter remains after the message is displayed, so if the page is refreshed, or if the user clicks back to that page later, the message displays again. I am looking for a way to do what I described above, but only show the message the first time. I would like to avoid creating a database entity for each result message with an attribute for whether it's been viewed already or not as that seems like overkill. How would you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to POST the form to next-page.php, then execute this code on the page:

```
if (isset($_POST['form_element']))
    include("form-process.php"); //Or whatever page the DB update goes in
```

**Edit:** You can also do it with Javascript. Put this on the page where your form is:

```
$("#ajax_submit").click(function(){
    $("#ajax_form").submit();
    window.location=location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname+"nextpage.php";
});
```

On a page where the form is like:

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="POST" id="ajax_form">
    Name: <input name="username"><br>
    Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="ajax_submit">
</form>
```

Comment: My concern with this method would be that users would click back or refresh and then get the warning about sending a POST again..

Comment: I edited my post to show an AJAX method of doing, then. This will solve your problem.

Comment: So with the AJAX method are you suggesting still to POST the message parameter or use a GET parameter with the window.location javascript?

Comment: The AJAX method will basically be the same as the user clicking "submit" but without the redirect. The user is then redirected in the next line, to the page that you want him to be on.

Comment: But where would you put the parameter to display the results message? With the POST or with the redirect as a GET?